# Best way to simplify boolean check in c# with a lot of different possibilities

Tags: c#, linq, boolean

How can I reduce this code? I have transferId, weekId and lineId and I want to be able to query the database based on if the url parameters where given or not.

Example:

route/Query?transferId=5325&lineId=10

or

route/Query?weekdId=11

and so on...

```
public async Task<ICollection<TransferEntity>> GetQueryAsync(string transferId, int? weekId, int? lineId)
    {
        if (Helpers.NullOrWhiteSpaceAll(transferId, weekId.ToString(), lineId.ToString()))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (!Helpers.NullOrWhiteSpaceAny(transferId, weekId.ToString(), lineId.ToString()))
        {
            return await _context.Transfers.Where(x => x.TransferId == transferId && x.WeekId == weekId && x.LineId == lineId).ToListAsync();
        }
        if (Helpers.NullOrWhiteSpace(transferId))
        {
            if (!Helpers.NullOrWhiteSpaceAny(weekId, lineId))
            {
                return await _context.Transfers.Where(x => x.WeekId == weekId && x.LineId == lineId).ToListAsync();
            }
            else if (!Helpers.NullOrWhiteSpace(weekId))
            {
                return await _context.Transfers.Where(x => x.WeekId == weekId).ToListAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return await _context.Transfers.Where(x => x.LineId == lineId).ToListAsync();
            }
        }
        else if (Helpers.NullOrWhiteSpace(weekId))
        {
            if (!Helpers.NullOrWhiteSpaceAny(transferId, lineId.ToString()))
            {
                return await _context.Transfers.Where(x => x.TransferId == transferId && x.LineId == lineId).ToListAsync();
            }
            else if (!Helpers.NullOrWhiteSpace(transferId))
            {
                return await _context.Transfers.Where(x => x.TransferId == transferId).ToListAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return await _context.Transfers.Where(x => x.LineId == lineId).ToListAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return await _context.Transfers.Where(x => x.TransferId == transferId && x.WeekId == weekId).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Linq-to-SQL will combine multiple `Where` clauses into single query - so you can simply add them as needed and execute at the end:

```
var transfers = _context.Transfers;

if (!Helpers.NullOrWhiteSpaceAny(transferId))
{
    transfers = transfers.Where(x => x.TransferId == transferId);
}
if (weekId.HasValue)
{
    transfers = transfers.Where(x => x.WeekId == weekId);
}

return _context.Transfers == transfers? null : // did not add anything
    await  transfers.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help guys but this is a better way to do it.
I have transferId, weekId, lineId
I want to only search by those that are not null or whitespace
I realized that whitespace can be ignored because the input that I get will never be whitespace

This is my solution

```
public async Task<ICollection<TransferEntity>> GetQueryAsync(string transferId, int? weekId, int? lineId) =>
        await _context.Transfers.Where(x => (transferId == null || x.TransferId == transferId) && (weekId == null || x.WeekId == weekId) && (lineId == null || x.LineId == lineId)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: If your requirements change then you should update your question by appending the change at the end. With this answer you have invalidated the question. Can you please attempt to make the question consistent with this answer **without** invalidating the other answers?

Answer (score -1):

Try this. First, make a flag enum of all singular parameters and their possible combinations:

```
public enum ParamSet { none = 0, transferId = 1, weekId = 2, lineId =4,
  // composite values
  transferId_weekId = 3
}
```

here first line are individual param flags: if param is not null, the flag is set, otherwise not. Second line is for allowed parameter combinations. For instance, transfer and week ids. It's 3 because 1+2;

Then, analyse the current parameter values:

```
ParamSet currentParams = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(transferId) ? ParamSet.none : ParamSet.transferId) | (weekId == null ? ParamSet.none : ParamSet.weekId) | (lineId == null ? ParamSet.none : ParamSet.lineId);
```

Finally, get a `switch`:

```
      switch(currentParams)
  {
    case ParamSet.transferId_weekId: break;
    case ParamSet.transferId: break;
    default: throw new Exception("Unsoppurted param config");
  }
```